# returns null while returning from nested loop

Tags: java

i was returning a array String[] data, but it returns NULL.
i tried to store array in data[] but not worked,
now i have values in Strings(name,phone,temp,password) but cant return..

```
public String[] searchUserData(String email) {

String[] data= null;
String temp,name,phone,password;

    if (cr.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            temp = cr.getString(2);

            if (temp.equals(email)) {

                //data[0]= cr.getString(1);
                //data[1]= cr.getString(2);
                //data[2]= cr.getString31);
                //data[3]= cr.getString41);

                name = cr.getString(1);
                phone = cr.getString(3);
                password = cr.getString(4);

                Log.i("Values", name+" "+phone+" "+email+" "+password);


            } 
        } while (cr.moveToNext());
        cr.close();
    }
    db.close();

    return data;

}
```

Comment: Well, if `data = null`, and if `data` is never instantiated... `return data` returns obviously `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `String[] data = new String[4];` will start you off.

This gives you 4 elements in the `data` array, which are initially set to `null`.

These can be accessed using `data[0]` through to `data[3]`: array indexing in Java is 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

you have not created the String array object

```
public String[] searchUserData(String email) {

String[] data= new String[4];
String temp,name,phone,password;

    if (cr.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            temp = cr.getString(2);

            if (temp.equals(email)) {

                data[0]= cr.getString(1);
                data[1]= cr.getString(2);
                data[2]= cr.getString31);
                data[3]= cr.getString41);

                name = cr.getString(1);
                phone = cr.getString(3);
                password = cr.getString(4);

                Log.i("Values", name+" "+phone+" "+email+" "+password);


            } 
        } while (cr.moveToNext());
        cr.close();
    }
    db.close();

    return data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some other problems:

1. No declaration of cr and db. One presumes these are instance variables that have been appropriately set elsewhere in the code.
2. You set the same data array over and over again until cr.moveToNext() returns false. Perhaps you mean to break out of the loop after setting the data array when temp matches email ?